# Wi-Fi Availability check in background process android

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, background-process, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an application with the Wireless activity. I have to work with the internet by using the WLAN(Wireless LAN) and my Bluetooth activity needs to work all the time.

Here, some times i got the problem with my wi-fi / Bluetooth device as Out-of coverage area. I have worked with out the knowledge of this and while submitting the process i came to know that Internet not Available..

I need to update the data every time while i processed in the application. If i have a Wi-fi / Bluetooth Streangth notification embedded in my program or application means i could come to know, if the Wi-fi / Bluetooth streangth went to low.

Help me to resolve this Problem. Thank you..

Comment: Hello, I am a little confused by the working in your post. Is this a WiFi issue, or a bluetooth problem? You are talking about both wifi and bluetooth in your post, and I find it unclear what the actual problem device is

Comment: Actually, while i'm moving with my Tablet i may gone to the Wi-Fi out of coverage area, that time i couldn't pass the data to the Server..

Comment: Ok, whats the relation to bluetooth then?

Comment: While crossing the Coverage area, i plan to display a notification that, "Bluetooth  Streangth is low / Out of coverage"..

Comment: I'm accessing the internet through the Bluetooth / wi-fi

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking how to check if your WiFi is connected, if so you can use ConnectivityManager

```
ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)
     getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifi = conman.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if(wifi.isConnected()) {
   // yay! your connected
}
```

Now, to have the above running in the background, you can implement the above in a service running in the background and communicating with your activity. Look here for an example to help you get started with background services.

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/running-service-in-background-on.html

In a service, you will need to get the ConnectivityManager the following way, since you need to get the application context first

```
ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)
     getApplicationContext().getgetSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Can i check this in a sequence of time period, simultaniously?

Comment: I can't see why not, you could put it in a service or something like that. It depends on what you want to do really (as in will the checks only be needed when running in the foreground etc.)

Comment: Ariva, that depends on the background process :) if you implement it as a service, you will have access the application context (and thereby getSystemService)

Comment: Ariva, well, basically, you can have a service running in the background. And a service has access to the application context, so you can run getSystemService. Hence, the above example should do fine within a service (running in the background:))

Comment: Can you give any Example program or any tutorial for this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20694/discussion-between-arivazhagan-and-justdanyul)

Answer (score 0):

going by what @JustDanyul said you could simply modify the it so that its always checks its connectivity by using a  while loop instead of an if statement so that while your connected to the internet your app does one thing and then when disconnected do something else